# needs previous value record in current records filed using triggers on and using salesforce admin

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a below requirement,
I have created an object for calculating mileage vs cost for bike

I have the below fields in my object:
Object Name: (API Name)

```
Mileage_vs_Cost__c
Bill Amount
Bill_Amount__c
Current Reading
Current_Reading__c
Date
Date__c
Past Reading
Past_Reading__c
PetrolUser
Name__c
```

Petrol User is a master object for( Mileage_Vs_ Cost__c) object
Example :
 For the first time when I save my record, current reading is zero fueled on 3/21/2016,

I will be travelling whole month and next time when I am ready to fuel the petrol , I will be entering some 1000 kms as current reading and when I do this process I want the past reading
(i.e; previous month's current reading which is 0(zero) when I filled fuel on 3/21/2016) to  get populated in Past_reading__c filed of my record….

So that I can calculate mileage = (Current reading - past reading) and based on this further developments I can do on the page; can any one help me in this requirement I feel grateful and I am trying it using List and triggers and am failing…

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can access the old values using `trigger.oldMap`. I highly recommend looking up trigger best practices and implementing a framework. At the very least, implement a service layer to get the code out of the trigger body.

```
if (trigger.isBefore && trigger.isUpdate)
{
    for (Cost_vs_Mileage__c record : trigger.new)
    {
        record.Prior_Reading__c = trigger.oldMap.get (record.Id).Current_Reading__c;
    }
}
```